# Nuget SQL Compact, deployable assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, .net-assembly

The DLL files under **_bin_deployableAssemblies** belongs to SQL Compact....

apparently do not get installed via Nuget (neither with Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact 4.0.8854 or EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.1.1).  Exclude the **_bin_deployableAssemblies** from Git and when a co-worker cloned the project only "shadow" copies of the dll files were present.  The automatic build copy process from **_bin_deployableAssemblies** to **bin** failed for him.

Don't have a history of my Nuget installations but I suspect either a package setup up this dll or I did it somehow in the solution.

Read Michael Dudley's [blog](http://provenstyle.com/about/) about pushing SQL Compact with projects.  Along with a Nuget [setup](http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/10/entity-framework-6-and-sql-server.html) that tries to address 4.0.0.1 assemblies.

Is there a reason why these dll are missing when cloning the project?  Why the shadow copies then?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why these dll are missing when cloning the project?

Perhaps because executable files and bin directories aren't usually considered source files under version control.

> Why the shadow copies then?

The "shadow" copies are presumably the items in the project file, i.e. the DLLs are identified in the project file